# How does ConcurrentHashMap handle rehashing?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I am wondering how does ConcurrentHashMap handle rehashing while another thread is still writing on another segment/partition.

As far as I understand, ConcurrentHashMap locks the segment independently, so for example:

If Thread1 writes to the segment1 slightly before Thread2 writes to segment2, then what happens if it requires the table to resize and rehash after Thread1 insertion, but Thread2 is in the middle of the writing operation?
Does it lock the whole map for rehashing? And does it have something like "tell Thread2 to stop and wait until the rehash is done"? Because Thread2 may have a chance to end up writing segment1 after the table resize, correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Every segment is separately rehashed so there is no collision.

`ConcurrentHashMap` is array of specialized hash tables which are called `Segments`

From the source code

```
final Segment<K,V>[] segments;

/**
 * Segments are specialized versions of hash tables.  This
 * subclasses from ReentrantLock opportunistically, just to
 * simplify some locking and avoid separate construction.
 */
```

And if you check the method which returns Segment

```
final Segment<K,V> segmentFor(int hash) {
    return segments[(hash >>> segmentShift) & segmentMask];
}
```

So if you call `put` it first determines the `Segment` using `segmentFor` and then call put on that `Segment`

`put` source code

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (value == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    return segmentFor(hash).put(key, hash, value, false);
}
```

Comment: So for the scenario that I provided above. It will first rehash segment1 and then leave segment2 alone since someone is writing it, and then move on to the next segment, and at the end rehash segment2 once it's active ?

Comment: No it is like segment is rehashed independently. so if segment 1 needs rehash then and then only it will be rehashed.

Comment: So the hashing is handle separately ?

Comment: @user1389813 Every segment handles its hashing.

Comment: I am wondering how does put() work then ? i mean how does it know which segment to go to and then hash there ? is it like double hashing ?

Comment: @user1389813 That is why I added source code for `segmentFor` method also to avoid confusion. Also added put method source.

Answer (score 0):

In `ConcurrentHashMap` table array is created for per-segment. 
And array of Segments created based on `concurrencyLevel`.

```
    /**
     * The per-segment table. Elements are accessed via
     * entryAt/setEntryAt providing volatile semantics.
     */
    transient volatile HashEntry<K,V>[] table;
```

So REHASHING also will be done per segment's table. So this wont affect the table of another segment.

This is something like Array{Segments} of Array{elements} (2D). So very fast :)